# Logstash extract KV pairs only from certain lines

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I have a log file that looks like this :

2016 October 08 01:51:46 PM : Some text that I want to capture in a field 'text_message'
key1: 12. key2: 256.
key3: 45.0 key4: 102.3
...

So some lines start with a date and are followed by a text message. In that case I want to capture the date in a 'timestamp' field and the text in a 'text_message' field.

Lines starting with a date are followed by many lines from which I'd like to extract KV pairs.

How can I specify this if/else behaviour? I image I can use Grok for the timestamped lines and KV for the others (I managed to use KV correctly for the key-value lines already).

Comment: Can you post your Logstash config? What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: You can use if/else in your configuration, see [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/event-dependent-configuration.html#conditionals), including regex matching with =~